# SQL query help select from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have no idea how to finish this query....

The question asks:

> "For each person who acted in a movie in 2010, find their name
>   and total pay in all movies in which they have acted (i.e. including
>   those not in 2010)."

The table required: (where title = Movie title, and year = Movie year, and Pay = actors pay)

```
ActedIn (name:varchar, title:varchar, year:int, pay:real)
```

My query so far:

```
SELECT A.name, A.pay FROM ActedIn A WHERE A.year = 2010;
```

This returns:

```
+--------+--------+
|  Name  |   Pay  |
+--------+--------+
|  Dino  | 12.22  |
+--------+--------+
|  Miro  | 1238.22|
+--------+--------+
```

But, this only returns the pay for the money received for the specific movie made by the actor in 2010.

Now that I have the names of the actors I want to look up, I need it to find all the other movies they made (before or after 2010), and add TOTAL PAY for all the movies they were in.

I know I need to make another table to find all the movies those 2 actors acted in, and then merge the columns I think.

Any help?

Comment: You don't need another table, but you do need to use a subquery.

Comment: You don't need a subquery

Comment: Maybe 'need' is not the best word, however the best solution for such a simple problem would be to use a subquery.

Comment: @ShWiVeL No. The best solution would be to use a join

Comment: Why are we to assume that joining with an inline view would run any faster than this? We have no information that would let us determine that.

Comment: @ShWiVeL Please provide an example of IN (SELECT..) outperforming a JOIN on a properly indexed table (although, as GL demonstrates, I was wrong too!)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38f9e/1/0   vs.   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38f9e/3/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single aggregation and `having` clause:

```
select ai.name, sum(ai.pay)
from actedin ai
group by ai.name
having sum(case when ai.year = 2010 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of movies that each "name" acted in in 2010.  If this number is greater than 0, then the name is kept for the result set.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use exists with a subquery.

```
 select name, sum(pay)
   from actedin a
 where exists (select 1 from actedin b where a.name = b.name and year = 2010)
 group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, sum(pay)
  from actedin
 where name in (select name from actedin where year = 2010)
 group by name
```